# Finding limit of sequence of roots

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, contest-math

> Let $P_n(x)=x^n-x-1$, for $n>1$ a positive integer. Show that for each
>   $P_n$ has a unique positive root for each $n>1$ call it $\alpha_n$.
>   Show that $\alpha_n$ is irrational and find $\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\alpha_n-1)$.

I have shown that there is always a unique positive root in the interval $(1,2)$, and by rational root theorem there won't be any rational roots. I am stuck at finding the limit. Can someone help with that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you proved $1 < \alpha_{n} < 2, \forall n \ge 1\implies 2^{1/n} < \alpha_{n}\ < 3^{1/n}\implies \alpha_{n} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$. Also $n\left(\alpha_{n} - 1\right)= \dfrac{(1+\alpha_{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}-1}{\frac{1}{n}}\to \ln(1+1) = \ln2$ ( you can show with squeeze lemma ).

Answer (score 0):

We show that when $n \rightarrow \infty$, $x=1+\ln2/n$ is a root of the given equation
as $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [(1+\frac{ln 2}{n})^n-(1+\frac{ln 2}{n})-1] =\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} [2 -1-\frac{\ln2}{n}-1] =0.$$ Hence $a_n=1+\frac{\ln 2}{n}$, then finally $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n(a_n-1)=\ln 2.$$

Comment: How do you find the root for $x$? Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Simply because it satisfies the equation as a limit.