# Find the limit of $n(x_n -1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, limits

Consider the following polynomial: $x^n-x^2-x-1=0$. Then

a) Prove that there's only one root for degree $k$ function, denote it as $x_k$.

b) find
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty} n(x_n-1)
\end{align}

**My attempts**

a) it's not difficult to prove that there can't be more than one distinct root.

b) What I found here is that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ doesn't exists, otherwise, either

if $L<1$ then $L^2+L+1=L^n \to 0$ for all $n$ arbitrarily large. (Which is false since $L^2+L+1 > 0$)

if $L>1$ then $L^n \gg L^2+L+1$, which is also flawed.

and apparently $L=1$ isn't a solution because $1-1-1-1=(-2)$

But if there isn't a limit for $x_n$, then would $n(x_n-1)$ simply converges to infinity?

Is there any flaw in my argument?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The only possible way that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} n(x_n - 1)$ could converge to a finite value $L$ is if the $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n - 1)$ converges to $(0)$.  If you have the premise that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ does not exist, then you can infer that $(x_n - 1)$ can not go to $(0)$.

Comment: Do you mean only one positive root? For every even $n$, $-1$ solves the equation. Also be careful with the recursive formula, what you actually do is you pass to the limit with the expressions $x_k^k - x_k^2 - x_k - 1$ and while the limit is obvious for the last three terms it is not clear whether $x_k^k$ tends to 1 in the case $L=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us denote $p_n(x) = x^n - x^2-x-1$, and I'll assume that $n \ge 3$.

As mentioned in the comments, $p_n(-1) = 0$ for even $n$, so the correct statement can only be “$p_n$ has exactly one *positive* root.“

For $0 < x < 1$ is $x^n < x$ and therefore $ p_n(x) < -x-1 < 0$. For $x \ge 1$ is
$$
 p_n'(x) = nx^{n-1} - 2x - 1 \ge 3 x - 2 x - 1 > 0
$$
so that $p_n$ is strictly increasing on $[1, \infty)$. Also $\lim_{n \to \infty} p_n(x) = +\infty$. All this together implies that $p_n$ has exactly one positive root $x_n$.

We already know that $x_n > 1$, and from
$$
 p_n(2) = 2^{n}-7 \ge 1
$$
it follows that also $x_n < 2$.

Then
$$
 x_n = (1 + x_n + x_n^2)^{1/n}
$$
is in the range $(1, 7^{1/n})$, which implies that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 1$.

For the final step one can proceed as in [Finding limit of sequence of roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3360532/finding-limit-of-sequence-of-roots): From
$$
 n (x_n-1) = \frac{(1+x_n+x_n^2)^{1/n}-1}{1/n}
$$
one can conclude that that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} n(x_n - 1) = \ln(3) \, ,
$$
since $1+x_n+x_n^2 \to 3$, and for all $A > 0$
$$
 \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{A^t-1}{t} = \ln(A) \, .
$$